# How to measure Python import latencies

Tags: python, import

My django application takes forever to load so I'd like to find a way to measure the import latencies so I can find the offending module and make it load lazily.

Is there an obvious way to do this? I was considering tweaking the import statement itself to produce the latencies but I'm not sure exactly how to do that. I guess that it would be ideal to have the import tree (or DAG?) along with the latencies but just a list of latencies and import statements would be enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine [the `__import__` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=__import__#__import__) to log the start and end times (delegating everything else to the original built-in `__import__`).  That's exactly **the** way to "tweak the import statement" in Python: redefine `__import__`!

**Edit**: here's a simple example...:

```
import sys

import __builtin__
_orgimp = __builtin__.__import__

import logging
FORMAT = "%(asctime)-15s %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)

def __import__(name, *a):
  r = sys.modules.get(name)
  if r is not None: return r
  logging.info('import bgn %s', name)
  r = _orgimp(name, *a)
  logging.info('import end %s', name)
  return r
__builtin__.__import__ = __import__

import pyparsing
```

This shows, on my system:

```
2010-08-24 08:36:39,649 import bgn pyparsing
2010-08-24 08:36:39,652 import bgn weakref
2010-08-24 08:36:39,652 import bgn _weakref
2010-08-24 08:36:39,653 import end _weakref
2010-08-24 08:36:39,653 import end weakref
2010-08-24 08:36:39,654 import bgn copy
2010-08-24 08:36:39,655 import bgn org.python.core
2010-08-24 08:36:39,656 import end copy
2010-08-24 08:36:39,675 import end pyparsing
```

Of course you can parse this log to show the nesting (what module first-imported what other modules) *and* "attempted imports" that failed (here, that of `org.python.core` from `copy`, no doubt in a `try`/`except` statement) as well as the time at which each import begins and concludes (the latter only if it does conclude, of course, not if it fails -- easy to tweak with `try`/`finally` or whatever to get the exact behavior you prefer!-).

Comment: Thanks Alex! This helps a lot.